# Google sitemap error ParseEntityRef: no name on opencart 3

Tags: xml, opencart, opencart-3, xml-sitemap

It's my first time using opencart and Google sitemap
Here is my error 
Sitemap URL https://www.startpc.ro/index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap
Character Set
Sitemap is valid    No

> Warnings  - Errors     [68] xmlParseEntityRef: no name on line 1 [68]
>   xmlParseEntityRef: no name on line 1

I don't understand where is my problem
Can someone please explain me how to fix it?
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

**How to Setup Google Sitemap in OpenCart 3.x**

Time to learn about the Google Sitemap and how to set it up in your new OpenCart 3 installation.

A Sitemap is an organized list of all the web pages in your store, which makes it easier for search engines like Google to scan them. This allows Google to find an index of all the content in your site faster and easier.

In OpenCart, it’s very easy to set up your Sitemap using the Extension system.

[Video Tutorials Click Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHz2VSv6n5E)

The first step is to go to your OpenCart admin and go to Extensions and then Extensions again.

Click the dropdown and select Feeds.

You will see the Google Sitemap extension. Hit the install button and then click Edit.

The first field is to just enable and disable the status of the sitemap. The second field is to enter the data feed URL.

Where to get this URL?

Go to Google Webmaster Tools. There will be a link in the description.

Click the Add a Property button and enter your store’s domain.

You will be asked to verify your ownership of the site.

You have a few ways to do this. We will use the recommended method, which is to upload an HTML verification document to our site.

To upload this document, we will use FileZilla. Access your OpenCart root directory and upload the file there.

Now, open the confirmation link and then verify your entry.

If everything is okay, go to the Crawl menu in your dashboard and click on Sitemaps.

There you’ll see the test/add sitemap button. You will need to enter the last part of your Data Feed URL excluding your site’s main domain.

Hit the submit button and your sitemap should now be ready and active.

Well, that’s all. Your site will now be easier for Google to digest and your pages will be indexed much faster.

Comment: Thank you for the answer . The problem is sitemap related . I've already added the site on google webmasters tool.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should see the line where the error was found.

In sitemap videos for example, this kind of error happen when you include ampersand `&amp;` caracter on the  atribute. This caracter isn´t allowed in this title, you just put the & in there.

Also If you have added your property in Google Search Console, you can check the xml and see where is the specific warning; even you can use the sitemap validator from Yandex webmaster tools.

I hope it's useful for you

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but I had the same issue myself and this was one of the google links.

The likely issue is the used of ampersands in your product names. The native Opencart sitemap generator isn't clever enough to replace & with & so you need to use an extension I'm afraid.